# How to model the three-glass pouring puzzle as a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, greedy

I want to model the following puzzle with a graph.

> The barman gives you three
>   glasses whose sizes are 1000ml, 700ml, and 400ml, respectively. The 700ml and 400ml glasses start
>   out full of beer, but the 1000ml glass is initially empty. You can get unlimited free beer if you win
>   the following game:
>   Game rule: You can keep pouring beer from one glass into another, stopping only when the source
>   glass is empty or the destination glass is full. You win if there is a sequence of pourings that leaves
>   exactly 200ml in the 700ml or 400 ml glass.

I was a little unsure of how to translate this problem in a graph. My thought was that the glasses would be represented by nodes in a weighted, undirected graph where edges indicate that a glass `u` can be poured into a glass `v` and the other way is the same, therefore a walk would be a sequence of pourings that would lead to the correct solution.

However, this approach of having three single nodes and undirected edges doesn't quite work for Dijkstra's algorithm or other greedy algorithms which was what I was going to use to solve the problem. Would modeling the permutations of the pourings as a graph be more suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store whole state as vertex. I mean, value in each glass is a component of state, hence state is array of `glassesCount` numbers. For example, initial state is `(700,400,0)`.

After that you should add initial state to queue and run [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). **BFS is appliable because each edge has equal weight =1**. Weight is equal because weight is a number of pourings between each state which is obviously = 1 as we generate only reachable states from each state in queue.

You may also use DFS, but BFS returns the shortest sequence of pourings because BFS gives shortest path for 1-weighted graphs. If you are not interested in shortest sequence of pourings but any solution, DFS is ok. I will describe BFS because it has the same complexity with DFS and returns better (shorter) solution.

In each state of BFS you have to generate all possible new states by pouring from all pairwise combinations. Also, you should check possibility of pouring.

For 3 glasses there are 3*(3-1)=6 possible branches from each state but I implemented more generic solution allowing you to use my code for N glasses.

```
public class Solution{


    static HashSet<State> usedStates = new HashSet<State>();
    static HashMap<State,State> prev = new HashMap<State, State>();
    static ArrayDeque<State> queue = new ArrayDeque<State>();
    static short[] limits = new short[]{700,400,1000};

        public static void main(String[] args){

            State initialState = new  State(new Short[]{700,400,0});
            usedStates.add(initialState);
            queue.add(initialState);
            prev.put(initialState,null);
            boolean solutionFound = false;


            while(!queue.isEmpty()){
                State curState = queue.poll();
                if(curState.isWinning()){
                    printSolution(curState);
                    solutionFound = true;
                    break; //stop BFS even if queue is not empty because solution already found
                }
                // go to all possible states

               for(int i=0;i<curState.getGlasses().length;i++)
                   for(int j=0;j<curState.getGlasses().length;j++) {
                       if (i != j) { //pouring from i-th glass to j-th glass, can't pour to itself
                           short glassI = curState.getGlasses()[i];
                           short glassJ = curState.getGlasses()[j];
                           short possibleToPour = (short)(limits[j]-glassJ);
                           short amountToPour;
                           if(glassI<possibleToPour) amountToPour = glassI; //pour total i-th glass
                           else amountToPour = possibleToPour; //pour i-th glass partially
                           if(glassI!=0){ //prepare new state
                               Short[] newGlasses = Arrays.copyOf(curState.getGlasses(), curState.getGlasses().length);
                               newGlasses[i] = (short)(glassI-amountToPour);
                               newGlasses[j]  = (short)(newGlasses[j]+amountToPour);
                               State newState = new State(newGlasses);
                               if(!usedStates.contains(newState)){ // if new state not handled before mark it as used and add to queue for future handling
                                   usedStates.add(newState);
                                   prev.put(newState, curState);
                                   queue.add(newState);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
            }
            if(!solutionFound) System.out.println("Solution does not exist");

    }

    private static void printSolution(State curState) {
        System.out.println("below is 'reversed' solution. In order to get solution from initial state read states from the end");
        while(curState!=null){
            System.out.println("("+curState.getGlasses()[0]+","+curState.getGlasses()[1]+","+curState.getGlasses()[2]+")");
            curState = prev.get(curState);
        }

    }

    static class State{

        private Short[] glasses;

        public State(Short[] glasses){
           this.glasses = glasses;
        }

        public boolean isWinning() {

            return glasses[0]==200 || glasses[1]==200;
        }

        public Short[] getGlasses(){
            return glasses;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other){
            return Arrays.equals(glasses,((State)other).getGlasses());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            return Arrays.hashCode(glasses);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> below is 'reversed' solution. In order to get solution from initial
>   state read states from the end

```
(700,200,200)
(500,400,200)
(500,0,600)
(100,400,600)
(100,0,1000)
(700,0,400)
(700,400,0)
```

Interesting fact - this problem has no solution if replace

> 200ml in g1 **OR** g2

to

> 200ml in g1 **AND** g2

.

I mean, state (200,200,700) is unreachable from (700,400,0)

Comment: I follow most of it, but how are you initializing every vertex? As I am assuming the vertexes are permutations of the states i.e every possible state is a vertex in the graph?

Comment: @joe, if I got you properly, you think each number is a state(complex object) and graph node is permutation of complex objects (states). But each number (amout in i-th glass) is not state is component of array which is actually state object. In other words, if you draw the graph each vertex will be noted with triplet (3 numbers) not one number. So, in my model initializing vertex == populating array, going to other state is create new array which differs from cur_state array in some cells (changed glasses)

Answer (score 1):

If we want to model this problem with a graph, each node should represent a possible assignment of beer volume to glasses. Suppose we represent each glass with an object like this:

```
{ volume: <current volume>, max: <maximum volume> }
```

Then the starting node is a list of three such objects:

```
[ { volume: 0, max: 1000 }, { volume: 700, max: 700 }, { volume: 400, max: 400 } ]
```

An edge represents the action of pouring one glass into another. To perform such an action, we pick a source glass and a target glass, then calculate how much we can pour from the source to the target:

```
function pour(indexA, indexB, glasses) {  // Pour from A to B.
  var a = glasses[indexA],
      b = glasses[indexB],
      delta = Math.min(a.volume, b.max - b.volume);
  a.volume -= delta;
  b.volume += delta;
}
```

From the starting node we try pouring from each glass to every other glass. Each of these actions results in a new assignment of beer volumes. We check each one to see if we have achieved the target volume of 200. If not, we push the assignment into a queue.

To find the shortest path from the starting node to a target node, we push newly discovered nodes onto the head of the queue and pop nodes off the end of the queue. This ensures that when we reach a target node, it is no farther from the starting node than any other node in the queue.

To make it possible to reconstruct the shortest path, we store the predecessor of each node in a dictionary. We can use the same dictionary to make sure that we don't explore a node more than once.

The following is a JavaScript implementation of this approach. Click on the blue button below to run it.

```js
function pour(indexA, indexB, glasses) {  // Pour from A to B.
  var a = glasses[indexA],
      b = glasses[indexB],
      delta = Math.min(a.volume, b.max - b.volume);
  a.volume -= delta;
  b.volume += delta;
}

function glassesToKey(glasses) {
  return JSON.stringify(glasses);
}

function keyToGlasses(key) {
  return JSON.parse(key);
}

function print(s) {
  s = s || '';
  document.write(s + '<br />');
}

function displayKey(key) {
  var glasses = keyToGlasses(key);
      parts = glasses.map(function (glass) {
        return glass.volume + '/' + glass.max;
      });
  print('volumes: ' + parts.join(', '));
}

var startGlasses = [ { volume: 0, max: 1000 },
                     { volume: 700, max: 700 },
                     { volume: 400, max: 400 } ];

var startKey = glassesToKey(startGlasses);

function solve(targetVolume) {
  var actions = {},
      queue = [ startKey ],
      tail = 0;
  while (tail < queue.length) {
    var key = queue[tail++];                          // Pop from tail.
    for (var i = 0; i < startGlasses.length; ++i) {   // Pick source.
      for (var j = 0; j < startGlasses.length; ++j) { // Pick target.
        if (i != j) {
          var glasses = keyToGlasses(key);
          pour(i, j, glasses);
          var nextKey = glassesToKey(glasses);
          if (actions[nextKey] !== undefined) {
            continue;
          }
          actions[nextKey] = { key: key, source: i, target: j };
          for (var k = 1; k < glasses.length; ++k) {
            if (glasses[k].volume === targetVolume) { // Are we done?
              var path = [ actions[nextKey] ];
              while (key != startKey) {               // Backtrack.
                var action = actions[key];
                path.push(action);
                key = action.key;
              }
              path.reverse();
              path.forEach(function (action) {        // Display path.
                displayKey(action.key);
                print('pour from glass ' + (action.source + 1) +
                      ' to glass ' + (action.target + 1));
                print();
              });
              displayKey(nextKey);
              return;
            }
            queue.push(nextKey);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

solve(200);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Neat! But the requirement is that either the 700 or the 400 ml glass should contain 200ml of beer, not the 1000ml glass. A run of your code ends with 200ml in the 1000ml glass.

Comment: I missed that requirement. Okay, let's modify this line: `for (var k = 0; k < glasses.length; ++k)` We just have to change `k = 0` to `k = 1`. Go ahead and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the idea of demonstrating the elegance of constraint programming after the two independent brute force solutions above were given. It doesn't actually answer the OP's question, just solves the puzzle. Admittedly, I expected it to be shorter.

```
par int:N = 7; % only an alcoholic would try more than 7 moves
var 1..N: n;   % the sequence of states is clearly at least length 1. ie the start state

int:X = 10;    % capacities
int:Y = 7;
int:Z = 4;
int:T = Y + Z;

array[0..N] of var 0..X: x; % the amount of liquid in glass X the biggest
array[0..N] of var 0..Y: y;
array[0..N] of var 0..Z: z;

constraint x[0] = 0; % initial contents
constraint y[0] = 7;
constraint z[0] = 4;

% the total amount of liquid is the same as the initial amount at all times
constraint forall(i in 0..n)(x[i] + y[i] + z[i] = T);
% we get free unlimited beer if any of these glasses contains 2dl
constraint y[n] = 2 \/ z[n] = 2; 

constraint forall(i in 0..n-1)(
  % d is the amount we can pour from one glass to another: 6 ways to do it
  let {var int: d = min(y[i], X-x[i])} in (x[i+1] = x[i] + d /\ y[i+1] = y[i] - d) \/ % y to x
  let {var int: d = min(z[i], X-x[i])} in (x[i+1] = x[i] + d /\ z[i+1] = z[i] - d) \/ % z to x

  let {var int: d = min(x[i], Y-y[i])} in (y[i+1] = y[i] + d /\ x[i+1] = x[i] - d) \/ % x to y
  let {var int: d = min(z[i], Y-y[i])} in (y[i+1] = y[i] + d /\ z[i+1] = z[i] - d) \/ % z to y

  let {var int: d = min(y[i], Z-z[i])} in (z[i+1] = z[i] + d /\ y[i+1] = y[i] - d) \/ % y to z
  let {var int: d = min(x[i], Z-z[i])} in (z[i+1] = z[i] + d /\ x[i+1] = x[i] - d)    % x to z
);

solve minimize n;

output[show(n), "\n\n", show(x), "\n", show(y), "\n", show(z)];
```

and the output is

```
[0, 4, 10, 6, 6, 2, 2]
[7, 7, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7]
[4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 2]
```

which luckily coincides with the other solutions. Feed it to the MiniZinc solver and wait...and wait. No loops, no BFS and DFS.